# Current Limiting Circuit with Comparator/ Threshold Comparator (current limit) switch Simulation

Tags: stepper-motor, h-bridge, comparator, current-limiting

I am driving a stepper motor with an H-bridge and hex inverter and need to create a circuit that limits the current. I need help designing a circuit with a comparator that detects a current greater than 500 mA.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What should happen if overcurrent occur?